# Installing eventFilter on QListView for indexWidgets

Tags: qt, mouseevent, qwidget, qlistview, qt-events

I have a customWidgets with some components (combobox, lineEdit, labels..etc), This customWidget is added to a QListView using setIndexWidget(QModelIndex,QWidget) , My requirement is that when i click any component on the customWidget the QListView item should get selected/focused.

How can I installEventFilter from cutomWidget to QListView, i have installed event filter for the customWidget.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

That is well described in [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#installEventFilter) of QObject.

You can try:

```
customWidget::installMyFilters()
{
    listView->installEventFilter(this);
}
```